# What does t0,t1,t2 and a0 mean in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I have been coding in Haskell for couple of weeks now and I keep on seeing errors with t0,t1,t2 and a0. I'm wondering, do they have any in particular meaning or they are just variables? I am asking because I would like to understand better the errors that the compiler spits at me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, they do not have any particular meaning. They're just variables denoting arbitrary type, as you have noticed. The numbering of these variables (`t0`, `t1`, `t2` etc.) is related to typechecking process internals and also does not mean anything in particular, as far as I know.

Answer (score 3):

Write explicit type signatures for your functions and then your errors will use the (hopefully more meaningful) names that you wrote.

Comment: Could you give an example? Not really sure how to "write explicit type signatures".

Comment: `f  :: Int -> Int` ; `f x = x + "hi"`

Comment: Explicit type signatures also help to keep errors localized to their function.